# Cannot connect to local SQL SSMS2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2014

I just installed SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and I am trying to log in to my server but it is not allowing me to log in. I have attached a screenshot but basically when I enter my server name is say "Cannot connect to MYSQLSERVER" I have attached that screenshot a well.

[image: Proof of running server]
[image: Error message.]

Comment: When you installed it, did you give it an instance name?  Is "mysqlserver" your actual machine name?

Comment: @JiggsJedi my Machine name is "SERVERPC" and I named the server "MYSQLSERVER" with an ID of "MSSQLSERVER"

Comment: try serverpc\mysqlserver in the connection box as "server name".  you have to specify machinename\instancename.  Or you can click the drop down, and pick "browse for more" to see if SSMS can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I needed to add my machine name to the server name. Thank you @JiggsJedi for making me realize this.